# Where to call the method in react component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react js. I have created a simple slider component. It's working but I want to ask if there is a right way to call the method? As of the moment I am calling it on the constructor. I would really appreciate any constructive criticisms. Thank you.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Slider extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            current: 4
        };

        this.current = this.state.current;

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.animate();
        }, 5000);
    }

    animate() {
        this.getCurrent();
        this.setState({
            current: this.current
        });
    }

    getCurrent() {
        this.current = (this.current >= this.props.slides.length - 1) ? 0 : this.current + 1;
        return this.current;
    }

    render() {
        var slides = this.props.slides;
        var slideList  = slides.map((slide, index) => {
            let slideClass = (index == this.state.current) ? 'slider-item active' : 'slider-item';
            return <div className={slideClass} key={index}><span>{slide}</span></div>;
        });

        return (
            <div className="slider-component">{slideList}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I think better option would be using `componentDidMount` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in `componentDidMount` like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.animate();
      this.timer = undefined
  }, 5000);
}
```

But don't forget to clear the timer on unmount like this:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  if (this.timer) {
    clearTimeout(this.timer)
  }
}
```

otherwise the code will break if this component is unmounted before 5000ms as it will try to do a `setState` in an unmounted component.

Comment: I copy paste this code but it's not working anymore?

Comment: Don't forget the `componentWillUnmount` part. That is equally important.

Comment: just a question, should the this.timer = undefined be in the unmount?

Comment: @B.V you mean in `this.timer = undefined` in `componentDidMount`? That is not necessary. Just to be on the safe side, I have put that.

Answer (score 1):

call it at componentDidMount()

Answer (score 1):

A constructor should ideally just construct the objects that should get used in the page later, if you want something to run on "mount" I would add it to `ComponentDidMount()` because if you've built the slider as its own component it would run the method once every time it gets "activated" so to speak.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I see it run only once.